# Sockets not working for React native and Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, react-native

So I am trying to connect my front-end app (react native app) to a backend server (node.js server) using sockets.
I have used socket.io for this purpose.
But the problem is the server-side code never goes into io.on('connection', ...) and therefore, the socket connection is not being established.

Any help is appreciated.

This is the React-native code - (index.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Alert,
    Button,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';


export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://localhost:3000');
    }
}
```

This is the server code -

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
      console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
      console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: but react-native support WebSockets. by default why external module?

Comment: Already tried WebSockets. Not working there too!